# Error reaching public extensions directory

Tags: drupal, civisms

I receive this error:  Extension download error
The CiviCRM public extensions directory at https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=4.7.9|cms=Drupal could not be contacted - please check your webserver can make external HTTP requests or contact CiviCRM team on CiviCRM forum.
However, from the browser I can go to that page and see a listing of extension.xml files. I'm trying to get the twilio sms extension installed.
Drupal 7.5 CiviCRM 4.7.9

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, some possibilities to evaluate:

- There is a problem on `civicrm.org`, but it only occurs on a subpage. For example, in v4.7.x (and maybe 4.6.x), it fetches the subpage `/single` (e.g. `https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=4.7.9|cms=Drupal/single`).
- There *was* a problem on `civicrm.org` and the failure got somehow cached. You could wait a while and try again -- or clear the caches. (Maybe use the "Support => Developer => API Explorer" to run `Extension.refresh` or `System.flush`.)
- Something in the web server environment is preventing it from making the request, e.g.

  - A security system (such as a firewall, suhosin, or php ini setting) interferes with outgoing requests.
  - The curl/http layer has a broken HTTP/SSL configuration.

In this particular case, I believe there was a change on `civicrm.org` which prevented it from correctly reading several of the XML files needed for `/single`, but that issue is now resolved.

(See also: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19090 )

Comment: Confirming that the issue has indeed been resolved.

Comment: I have used it and it works well for me.  Do we know why this would happen about once a week?

Answer (score 1):

There have been intermittent connectivity issues with our civicrm.org server this week. We've observed this ourselves as well for a number of our projects.

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine today. Must have been a temporary access issue.