# Extension download error

Tags: extension, error, civivolunteer

I am trying to install CiviVolunteer. When I go to extensions I get two errors:

"The CiviCRM public extensions directory at could not be contacted - please check your webserver can make external HTTP requests or contact CiviCRM team on CiviCRM forum."

and

"Unable to download extension from /single. Error Message: malformed"

Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related to your download problem, but CiviVolunteer is currently incompatible with CiviCRM versions 4.7.21 and greater.

There is a beta version described [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-310) which restores partial functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a permissions error; your webserver must have permissions to download files into a designated directory (which you specify in Adminster -> System Settings -> Directories); make sure you select a directory that is writeable; then you can install extensions for your CiviCRM.

Just re-reading your question; the above is part of the puzzle; the other part is that the CiviCRM extensions directory must be available; if that error persists please do report back. Please see here for a description on that error by one of the Core Team members: [Error reaching public extensions directory](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/error-reaching-public-extensions-directory)